# What function should i use to move a file with php?

Tags: php, html

I am uploading a file and saving it in a directory but the problem is : a file could be approved or denied , when it's denied it should be deleted from the directory(folder) this part is done , but when it's approved what should i use to move it to another directory , rename() or move_uploaded_file() and how to choose the path , should it be the name of the new folder(uploads/) or a specific path like (c:/xampp....).
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether your file is approved, THEN decide to remove/copy it, try this:

```
if ($something) { // condition for approval
    rename('./your/old/file.txt','./your/new/file.txt');
}else{
    delete('./your/old/file.txt');
}
```

As you can see from my code, files MUST BE relative to the current path OR the server root. (ex. `/server/root/file.txt`; `./relative/file.txt` OR `relative/file.txt`)

The `move_uploaded_file()` is a $_FILE thing. Don't use that for moving files that exist on your drive. It's for the upload form (check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) for details).